# Entity Framework - Create Composite PK from value object

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

How can i create a composite primary key in parent using fields in a valueobject ?
The valueobject will not have an own table in the database, i want these two props to be inserted into the parents table.

ie.

**Entities**

```
public class Parent 
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public MyValueObject MyValueObj { get;set; }
}

public class MyValueObject
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public int SSN { get;set; }
}
```

**DbContext for parent**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().Property(new { p.MyValueObj.Id, p.MyValueObj.SSN}).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I want the Parent table to look like this:

```
Composite PK
-----------
Id      SSN          Name
1       000000       Mikael
```

Comment: can you put the code of your models ?

Comment: @Sampath I've added the models now.

Comment: why do you need a value object here?

Comment: IRL the valueobject contains stuff and should be immutable, I simply create a new valueobject instead of updating the old.

Comment: What about `Parent : MyValueObject`?

Comment: Is this really good practice regarding to DDD ? The properties the object value vill have should not have anything to do with entity. The entity should remain same instance even if i create a new valueobject

Answer (score 0):

If you can use inheritance then it should look like this:

```
public class Parent : MyValueObject
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
}

public class MyValueObject
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public int SSN { get;set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().Property(new { p.Id, p.SSN}).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

The reason why your implementation won't work is pretty simple - Entity Framework just can't transform your complex object (which is set as property) to SQL field, so it will try to find it as a referenced object in other table. In the code I've provided you don't have any complex objects as a property, so EF will easily map all properties to SQL columns.

**UPDATE**
Actually, I did some more investigations and found an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types) stating that you can use complex types. I have never used this (and even seen) before, so can't describe you all sides of this question, but what I see from article is that this complex property can't be optional, so you will need always initialize that. Also I can only suppose, but probably you don't even need to mark all fields of that complex type as primary key, so you should have something just like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().Property(p => p.MyValueObj).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Not sure if that will work, just give it a try :)

Comment: Can't i use a Complex object and somehow create a composite key anyway ? but without a fk.